Gmail with Nextjs 15 Reply conversation
i working with Gmail in Nextjs 15, i can get all my email, sending email, but my reply has a problem.when i reply a mail, in my mail conversation i can fetch every previous mail which is fine. but the reciever is having a new mail. not in the same conversation we having
Here is my code
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function POST(req) {
  const { threadId, messageId, to, replyText, accessToken, from } = await req.json();
  const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2();
  auth.setCredentials({ access_token: accessToken });
  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });
   const rawMessage = [
    `From: ${from}`,
    `To: ${to}`,
    `In-Reply-To: ${messageId}`,
    `References: ${messageId}`,
    `MIME-Version: 1.0`,
    `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`,
    ``,
    replyText,
  ].join('\n');
  const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(rawMessage).toString('base64');
  try {
    const res = await gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId: 'me',
      requestBody: {
        raw: encodedMessage,
        threadId: threadId,
      },
    })
    .then((r) => {console.log(r)})
    .catch((err) => { console.log(err) });
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ status: 'Reply sent successfully' }), {
      status: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }), {
      status: 500,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  }
}


i tried to console.log every thing and it fine.
should my await gmail.users.messages.send add some fields or something so my reciever could in the same conversation mail
please help me.
i expect the reciever and i in the same conversation mail. the mail i reply in my conversation, but the reciever get a new mail

Changes: wrap the messageID, pass the threadID explicitly, add the base64 encoding
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function POST(req) {
  const { threadId, messageId, to, replyText, accessToken, from } = await req.json();
  const auth = new google.auth.OAuth2();
  auth.setCredentials({ access_token: accessToken });
  const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth });

  const rawMessage = [
    `From: ${from}`,
    `To: ${to}`,
    `Subject: Re: Your Subject Here`, // including the subject 
    `In-Reply-To: <${messageId}>`, // add angle brackets to prevent from detecting as plain text
    `References: <${messageId}>`,
    `MIME-Version: 1.0`,
    `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8`,
    ``,
    replyText,
  ].join('\n');

  
  const encodedMessage = Buffer.from(rawMessage)
    .toString('base64')
    .replace(/\+/g, '-')
    .replace(/\//g, '_')
    .replace(/=+$/, '');

  try {
    await gmail.users.messages.send({
      userId: 'me',
      requestBody: {
        raw: encodedMessage,
        threadId: threadId, // to ensure msg belongs to correct thread
      },
    });

    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ status: 'Reply sent successfully' }), {
      status: 200,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return new Response(JSON.stringify({ error: error.message }), {
      status: 500,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    });
  }
}


it still doesn't work. the reciever has a new conversation, but the sender is in the conversation. so confuse.
